# Как зашифровать код

Tags: javascript, cordova, key

Делаю приложение под андроид на JavaScript. Приложение билджу с помощью cordova, но проблема в том, что я использую api одного сервиса и его ключ прописан прямо в коде. По этому, если открыть через архиватор apk файл, и найти тот скрипт, то злоумышленник сможет воспользоваться моим ключом доступа. Как можно защититься в данном случае чтобы сохранить работоспособность приложения?

Comment: никак. если будет надо дешифруют. либо просто посмотрят сетевой трафик. перенесите эту функциональность на собственный сервер.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman смотря как зашифровать "если будет надо дешифруют"

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK ключ для дешифровки нужно хранить в приложении. Если ключ доступен, то надежность любого шифра близка к нулю.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Аминь:)